# jQuery page redirect not working on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.location

All,
I've got the following code:

```
var site_url = 'http://localhost/website/';
jQuery("#cancel_song_choice").click(function(event){
    cancel_url = site_url + "event-form";
    window.location.href(cancel_url);
});
```

Then I have the following HTML:

```
<button id="cancel_song_choice">Cancel Search</button>
```

When I click on the button it just keeps redirecting me back to the page that I'm on instead of going to the cancel url that I specified. I alert the cancel_url and it shows me the right one. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: use `window.location = cancel_url;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`href` is not a function, it's a property. Use: `window.location.href = cancel_url;`:

```
var site_url = 'http://localhost/website/';
jQuery("#cancel_song_choice").click(function(event){
    window.location.href = site_url + "event-form";
});
```

Check out [`window.location` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location).

Comment: Thanks that fixed one of my problems but for some reason this one still doesn't go back to the right URL. Any idea why it wouldn't do it for this one?

Comment: @user1048676, I'm not sure what you mean by `doesn't go back to the right URL`. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Yeah, it just refreshes the current page instead of redirecting the user to the site_url + event-form url.

Comment: Have you tried going directly to `'http://localhost/website/event-form`? The JS is as simple as it gets. If it's a valid URL, it should work.

Comment: Yes I have an it works fine. I agree that it's simple and that's why I'm not sure why it won't redirect my correctly. I guess I'll have to figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href=cancel_url;
```

should work